# Finding closed forms for the return values

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

```
int coffee(int n) {
   int s = n * n;
   for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
      s = s - q;
   for (int q = n; q > 0; q--)
      s = s - q;
   return s + 2;
}

int tea(int n) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n*n*n; i = i * 2)
        r++;
    return r * r;
}

int mocha(int n) {
    int r = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i = i+16)
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
            r++;
    return r;
}

int espresso(int n) {
    int j=0;
    for (int k = 16; coffee(k) * mocha(k) - k <= n; k+=16) {
        j++;
        cout << "I am having so much fun with asymptotics!" << endl;
    }
}
return j;
```

I am trying to find the returning value in terms of $n$ for `coffee`, `tea`, `mocha`, but I am stuck right now.

I know `coffee` will return 2 as the code follows:

$s = n^2$

$s = n^2 - \displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}q = n^2 - \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$

$s =  n^2 - \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} - \displaystyle\sum_{q=1}^n q = n^2 - \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2} - \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = 0$

Then, $s = 0 + 2$.

However, I can't seem to figure out `tea`, `mocha`, and `espresso`, because they don't follow +1 increments. Could anyone help me out how to compute the return value in terms of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

For coffee, you can replace the less than with $$\leq n^3-1$$ and since you’re counting the number of doubling, the answer will be $$\lfloor(\log(n^3-1,2))+1\rfloor$$

For mocha firstly notice inner loop is equivalent to `r+=i` and the sum becomes $$16 \cdot \lfloor(n/16)\cdot(\lfloor(n/16)+1)/2 \rfloor \rfloor$$

I’m pretty sure you can work out the last function. Sorry if this is unclear. I’ll edit this better when I get my laptop